# Modify parameter variable inside asp.net web api Controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, lowercase

This is very strange and I am probably missing something.

I have asp.net web api (running on .NET 4.5)

Inside one of the controller I have method:

```
[Route("/Search/{search}/{id:int}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Search(string search, int id)
{
....
search = search.ToLower();
```

At that moment the search still contains UpperCase.
But when I assign it to new variable like this:

```
var searchLower = search.ToLower();
```

Then searchLower contains lowercase.

Why cant I modify the parameter variable?

Comment: String functions don't modify anything, they return a new string. Strings are immutable ie they don't change. You aren't modifying the parameter, you are *assigning* a new value to it - something that isn't possible unless it's an out or ref parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But when I create string x = "Something"; and then do x = x.ToLower(); it works.. x is then lowercase.

Comment: Because it's a completely different thing. You assing the new string to a *variable*, not a parameter. Bad practice by the way, variables shouldn't be reused for different things. That makes debugging a lot harder and can lead to errors if you forget that branch have have changed the value

Comment: I dont see why changing value of variable is bad practice. We are not in functional programming where everything is supposed to be immutable. Anyway I still dont understand why I cant change value of parameter but ok,  I accept that as given in c#

Comment: I think in given context it is more confusing to have to create new variable then to modify the input parameter. Later in the method I want to use the lowercase version, but now I have to remember that the original is uppercase because it is not modifiable and I have to use some other variable..

Comment: And yet, you didn't know which variable is supposed to hold what. You thought that the value was the same as the parameter. You got confused because you tried to reuse not a variable, but a *parameter*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Wrong. I wanted to change the value of the parameter at the beginning of the method and not create second variable which creates confusion. Then you can by mistake use the parameter instead of the new variable, which would cause bugs.